# Migrating fonts from old to new server

Tags: fonts, migration

I have an "old" Ubuntu 11.10 server.
I have a new (Amazon EC2) Ubuntu 11.10 server.
I can only access them through the command line.

How can I migrate all the installed fonts from the old machine to the new machine?

I assume it is just copying some subdirectories. Is it that easy?

Background: I am running tests on my software, on both machines and it is giving different results, because the available fonts are different. (And the tests are sensitive to changes in pixels.)

Answer (score 1):

I researched the answer to my own question:

There are three phases required.

1. Find the font files.
2. Copy the missing files.
3. Update the font cache.

### Finding the Font Files

Look inside /etc/fonts/fonts.conf. It contains a number of different directories, marked with `<dir>` and `</dir>` tags.

In practice, I found 4 directories listed, of which 3 were empty or non-existent. Note: One is probably ~/.fonts, which is on a per-user basis.

### Copying the Font Files

Copy the font files from each directory into the corresponding directory on the target.

*I only bothered moving the files that were missing at the destination.*

### Updating the Font Cache

On the destination machine, run:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

(If fc-cache is not available, you need to install fontconfig, e.g. `sudo apt-get install 
fontconfig`)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by command line access ?

Do you have ssh access ??? Then you could copy the directories via scp.

`scp -r UID1@hist1:/dironhost1 UID2@host2:/dironhost2`

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid you've missed my point. I know how to copy files - I don't (didn't) know which files to copy and whether that was enough (it isn't).

Comment: Did you install the fonts via package manager or "manually"?

Comment: I did not deliberately install any fonts. There were all installed as side-effects of installing other packages (e.g. firefox).